# How to add nonce to google tag manager in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager

Currently i am using the package `React-gtm-module`, and i do not want to use unsafe-inline in CSP.so is there a way to add nonce to google tag manager in reactjs?

my current code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Router from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'
 
...
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module'
 
const tagManagerArgs = {
    gtmId: 'GTM-000000'
}
 
TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)
...
 
const app = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes} />, app)
```